# lock discord channel for a specific role

Tags: python, discord.py

hi I want to lock a discord channel for a specific role

For example we use this code to lock channel for @everyone

```
await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

if I am having a role called premium_members how can I lock them using discord.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a role by name using:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='premium_members')
```

and then use `role` instead of `ctx.guild.default_role`.

---

References:

- [guild.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)
- [utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.get)